# React - Update the css of a component multiple times a second (60)

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I was testing my websocket implementation by sending the mouse positions of my connected clients and rendering them with a red `<div>` box. When I added the "visualizer" to the connected clients the framerate was cut in half for each new client that connected.

I am not sure how to optimize something like this, I've tried minimizing the amount of looping (which helped a bit, but after some time it became as slow as my first approach).

The pointer is updated (debounced to) 60 times a second, what would I need to do to let that pointer update 60 times per second for at least four clients ?

I would like to keep those pointers, even though they are not part of the main application. React is probably not meant for this kind of thing, the question then is what should I have used instead ?

#### First Aproach

```js
const MousePointer = ({ GameLobby }) => {
  console.log(GameLobby);
  if (!GameLobby) return null;
  return Object.values(GameLobby).map((data, i) => {
    const pos = data.currentMousePosition ? data.currentMousePosition : [0, 0];
    const backgroundColor = 'red';
    return (
      <div
        key={i}
        css={{
          backgroundColor,
          height: '15px',
          width: '15px',
          boxSizing: 'border-box',
          position: 'absolute',
          left: pos[0],
          top: pos[1],
        }}></div>
    );
  });
};
```

#### One less loop

```js
const MousePointer = ({ GameLobby }) => {
  if (!GameLobby) return null;
  const {
    [Object.keys(GameLobby)[0]]: {
      backgroundColor = 'red',
      currentMousePosition: pos = [0, 0],
    },
  } = GameLobby;
  return (
    <div
      key={1}
      css={{
        backgroundColor,
        height: '15px',
        width: '15px',
        boxSizing: 'border-box',
        position: 'absolute',
        left: pos[0],
        top: pos[1],
      }}></div>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, rerendering at that rate will cause performance problems. You should try attaching a [callback ref](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html#how-can-i-measure-a-dom-node) to the `div` and updating only the properties that need to change using `setInterval`.

In order to check the most updated version of GameLobby without rerendering, you will have to refer it some other way (it can't be a prop). One very easy (and extremely questionable) way to do this is by sticking it on the window object or creating another global. I have also seen people add variables as instance properties of their components.

You might also just choose to handle the cursor ghosts outside of your React tree, right when you receive the GameLobby object. Probably easy enough to just append absolutely positioned divs directly to the DOM.

Note that these patterns shouldn't be generalized for other things you build in React, I would categorize them as "dirty tricks" that you need in rare situations (usually related to animation).

Comment: The component at max re-rendered every 16ms beause it was debounced to do that. Using `setInterval` seems unecessary in that context. So in conclusion removing the frequently updating elements from the react tree seems to be the most sensible thing to do.